# Area Range Chart with Vega

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vega

I basically want to have an area range chart similar to what Highcharts is capable of: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange

[image]

I looked at the examples and documentation but i am still not sure if area range charts are possible.

This is about grouping multiple data points into one. If you are zoomed in you see an ordinary line chart. If you zoom out and the chart no longer can show each data point separately, it basically shows a range of min/max values for a date range per horizontal pixel.

Is this possible with vega and how would the spec look like?

## Edit

Made a first working [prototype](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgFY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwANgAMuxREgpG1fFoAs%20w1ELo1axjOpbRNyGvR5MOANpKIUAhgqBl0VGQtSG92ABtImxDICnRY1mRYLX8QkKCcpNYtAEZE-KgKLQAmAA5S-MhlLQBmXQCcgF864LyyqEKcSq6kipxRNzb6xpw9CeDO2cCF4Mh%20sCah5ZGwC0GloyntiyX53p6ylcsNoy2miyuVS1FjjbP61fHe6%20bte4bmgHZnktXjkLtNflsLLU9g8cFDjrMALptdpKRHuBCpDJZNogyBhCJRAAemPiClm0QAnoRIjhILEnMh0AAncn1ZnoZy0lTqTRdSAAL2QzO4WgAZqlYMh%20WpuBgnFoQUZPN4ojEyRtIGLGMhYmoooVZqiQiduhSCdzIJTSQkKXhqZaGTImaz%20RyuVETGY8GzQTJGPBuXhmel%20UKReLJdKKbL5XIcEqoCqfFB1bbelqdXqohUjSi0e4MMyANaZPy4u0OqIspm%20pJikWoRUeLwp6LoOKRU1JZAyeDcNTcxOQXt4YWKmGQInNm3E2fyKDa3X6umFbvnSkz%20BYqLW7caxdZlflSDr%20qUypbnd0vc7heZ5dRRpn0Ha2KxZspNKW2Bj3VxdJTwRfJjTmNEQHaIA)

## Edit 2

Found an [example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/area.html#ranged) in the documentation of vega-lite

## Edit 3

[Combination of area range with master/detail](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCh5mY5NigBlZOgI6wAFTSFkAJ2OtryMACV0S6slVgATAAYAjF4ivn4ArGoakAAmxpg4wJD2YnpRMXxGJsgiAO7pKNZ08LAUkAC+6hCQFPDK8MZ6ANoaEKAQrVBZjJEsetIAHD7lbbjIjNT4egDMPgNNrZAY1gDWyegOmINtkMhK1ZGMbnotQxUAHoezx5DoJ4ywh5BaeDrJpRvHUABmjMhikcnReF0b0uCHQzziUW4GH291gP2Q8C0ymS7GsrFgiFKZQuQweAE8rMlAahCNxbEkcRBse8oHjzjSKo9wVAACLoRhiPHmSw2OwOZyudxgAAUAGEAJThBmfb6-ImWAD6GDOwNxeAJuhwkAAjqxXI9jIwqFKGVdqNQHLRAcllZBKWBqe9IHivPcvj8-lriYQlTDPGaLcJrVrUDDHZduIR0PBmHSIRQwaxNWAfHQAOwlHGZtrhsBHTYdLqYnB9GaXFCjcY4ABsZdxC2WWokSiBOMgcJ0iJ4Kji9sgqPRxbz9sZGuS+0B1gTSU8I6g212+2odxw9UgZwAuvbs0NcxUF9w9gdezT1-TTe65VqAa3pfjCV7LGSwSbT9dbvcmcnIGzrTvjnucxxsOd6Xp6miKqGKiqps6oPlAur6swhrGjBczviueYPIw8CLKK3CsEoeCTP6FqdHoHxgnC-pfi8-67lmsw7luJRAA)

Comment: Do you want to have the solution with Vega lite? D3 support this by default using [brushing and zoom](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_brush.html#brushingforzoom)

Comment: Vega-lite would be my prefered solution. Veta as a fallback is fine too.